# Blender Asset Browser - Assets do not update in scene when saving source content

Tags: modeling, objects

I made an asset in a custom Asset Library location.  I open a new instance of blender, and place the assets.  However, when I update the assets in the Library the assets in the other scene do not update.

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: The Asset Browser is not yet officially released and it may change a lot in the few coming weeks / months so you won't have definitive answers on this site. That being said it seems the default behaviour when dragging from the Asset Browser is to Append the objects, which does not retain the link from the original file. I'm sure this will be changed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

When you dragged the assets into the scene, you had the asset browser set to append. From your description, you expected it to link. Choose that in the drop-down at the top of the asset browser, and dragging will link assets instead of appending them.